# get jquery to return font-size in points

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I use .css('font-size') in jquery, it returns the value in pixels, is there any way to making it to give it in points ? it's because I want to use it in php gd, and it requires the font size to be in points

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fontSize = ...
var points = parseInt(fontSize) * 72 / 96
```

Comment: My initial reaction was to shout "No! You can't assume a DPI of 96!". However, after doing some poking around it seems that GD2 is … rubbish. It looks like it has a hardcoded internal DPI of 96, so this is possibly a reasonable assumption to make. (It's also something that would discourage me from using GD in the first place).

Comment: so do u have any better suggestion instead of gd ? :s

Answer (score 3):

If your `font-size` is defined in `pt` then you may access the `fontSize` property of `element.style` as follows...

```
var element = document.getElementById('my_element'),
    //return size as it is defined 
    fontSize = element.style.fontSize;
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the above with a slight correction:
(parseFloat($(this).css("font-size")) * 72.0 / 96.0).toFixed(2)