# i set font-size to 16pt but when i fetch it, it returns 21px. Can i get it to return pt?

Tags: jquery, css, computed-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get jquery to return font-size in points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357863/get-jquery-to-return-font-size-in-points)

Using jQuery, I'm setting something to 16pt as that is what my previous versions of my web application did. The issue is that some point after I set my code as follows:

```
$(SELECTED).css("font-size","16pt");
```

I would need to fetch it.  When I fetch it, it doesn't return 16pt, but instead 21px.  Is there either a conversion ratio I can use, or a way to fetch 16pt?

```
var fetched_size = $(SELECTED).css("font-size");
```

### Is there an option you need to pass in, or a different way of handling it?

As a follow up to this question, i had noticed that things are not looking they way they should on what i am building.  The textbox holding my data seems to be holding certain information.  Do you know why the following would not work?

```
var x = "32";
$("#fontsize").val(decodeURIComponent(x));  //this points to a input:text
 //the above statement doesnt seem to override the current contents with the value of x.
```

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357863/get-jquery-to-return-font-size-in-points

Comment: I went there.  Thanks for the information.  Im going to try to do that.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the solution there is to scale it to 96 DPI because that's the hardcoded DPI value for his application which uses GD2. You should read the answer from @Kostia for more information about px vs pt.

Comment: @Silox There’s no reason to convert from pt to px and back. Just access the pt value directly.

Comment: @JoshLee how would we be going about that?  I store it in PT, but when i fetch it, it seems to fetch in PX.  How do i access the PT value directly when it seemed to default it to PX naturally?

Comment: @Fallenreaper Access `.style.fontSize` on the element. This jQuery function is going out of its way to give you the computed style.

Comment: so jquery seemss to default it to PX then?  If i do .style.fontsize, it will keep it all the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `css` is for accessing the computed style. Just use the build-in `style` property directly:

```
var fetched_size = $(SELECTED)[0].style.fontSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not use pt for web at all. Either use px, or ems. Points (pt) were created for print design and make very little sense in screen-based usage.

EDIT: furthermore, because pt sizes were never made to be used on screen, there is no way to exactly convert between pt and px. Here is a rough [conversion chart](http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html)

You can read more about using ems/px here: http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: I was trying to figure that out as well.   Yea, my company has a web application which is built by a team using a windows form designing tool.  Im remaking the tool, but 200M records are based on PT and not PX.... so i was just trying to maintain the current company standards.

Comment: The fact that PT sizes weren't meant to be used on screen is negligent.  Sometimes it isn't about what is on screen, but about what is happening on the server.  For instance, the GD library uses PTs for the size of text.  I understand the heart of what you're saying: "Use the proper tools for the job", but at the same time, we can't always assume the conditions for the job.

Comment: @TimBolton Good point, totally agree. But then again, having been told nothing about the conditions, and making no assumption, I can only recommend the 'most correct' solution.

Comment: @Kostia Yes, but recommending not using PT's at all isn't a solution to the question asked.  He was trying to solve a specific problem, of converting from PX to PT, or getting the browser to give him the PT's when the units for the specified element were in PX.  Going into why it's bad to use PT's instead of PX/EM isn't the "most correct solution", it's an opinion.  Though the edit did bring in some solutions.

Comment: @TimBolton Understood. But its sort of like answering a question about "How to use tables to lay out my website". A responsible answer would, in my opinion, say that tables shouldn't be used for non-tabular data.

Comment: @Kostia ugh... this is degrading quickly.  I would disagree with that point.  I would say that it is akin to someone saying, "How do I use tables in my website?", rather than "How do I use tables to layout my website?"  And here's why... when you're told that you're using tables to layout a website, you are given direction as to the purpose and functionality of what they're asking.  With OP's question, we weren't.  He just wanted to know how to convert mathematically, or how to have it done for him.

Comment: @Kostia (continued) now the reason I was responding to your comment in the first place is because OP said it was a web application.  And I have dealt with a lot of web apps that work with PTs and the GD library.  One common problem that people find is that things are different when you're taking text from the browser (px) and trying to make it an image. The GD2 library uses PTs, as I mentioned. The point wasn't to be "right", or "correct", but more along the lines of "let's answer the question OP asked, instead of the one we think he should be asking." Going to PX may cause more unneeded work.

Comment: @TimBolton degraded indeed. My point was pt should not be used for displaying type, and the OP didn't say it was for GD. In this way, my analogy was perfectly valid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15778/discussion-between-tim-bolton-and-kostia)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the conversion ratio this way:

```
var ptToPx,
    o=document.createElement('div');
o.style.width='1000pt';
document.body.appendChild(o);
ptToPx=o.clientWidth/1000;
document.body.removeChild(o);
o=null;
var pxToPt=Math.pow(ptToPx,-1);
```

Then,

```
alert('10px are '+10*pxToPt+'pt');
alert(10+'pt are '+10*ptToPx+'px');
```