# How to get .css('font-size') to return points?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My text area has a `font-size = 14pt` but when I try and fetch it using jquery it returns me the data in pixels. Does anybody know how to get the values in points?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get jquery to return font-size in points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357863/get-jquery-to-return-font-size-in-points)

Comment: .css('font-size') will give you only `px`

Comment: You are saying that `I try and fetch it using jquery it returns me the data in points`.. And again you are asking for the same thing `Does anybody know how to get the values in points?` .. If you are already getting in points then why are you asking this question ??

Comment: If that `font-size` set in element style attribute/property, you can get it like `node.style.fontSize`. In other case you should get value in px `getComputedStyle( node ).fontSize` then convert it into pt

Comment: You can convert Pixels to Points http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139655/convert-pixels-to-points