# How to apply css to all html elements in a div selector with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to apply css `font-size` by a jquery on click to every element under div selector. But I can't make them affect. This is how I tried.

**CSS**

```
#reading_pane{
font-size:14pt;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="reading_pane">
<p>this is a text</p>
<span>this is another text</span>
</div>
<a id="incfont">A+</a>
<a id="decfont">A-</a>
```

**javascript**

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#incfont').click(function(){    
        curSize= parseInt($('#reading_pane span, p').css('font-size')) + 2;
  if(curSize<=20)
        $('#reading_pane').css('font-size', curSize);
        });  
  $('#decfont').click(function(){    
        curSize= parseInt($('#reading_pane').css('font-size')) - 2;
  if(curSize>=12)
        $('#reading_pane').css('font-size', curSize);
        }); 
 });
```

As the detailed above. I need every `<p>` and `<span>` in `div#reading_pane` change the size on each `a` clicked.

Comment: Tested and works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hej1so76/

Comment: Is this `<a id="incfont">A+</font>
<a id="decfont">A-</font>` correct ? I guess the closing tags should be `</a>` ?

Comment: The code, when fixed (manually or by a browser’s error correction), works in the sense of increasing or decreasing some font size. But it is illogical, as it sets the childre’ns font size to 2 pixels larger than the parent size, whereas the decrease operates on the parent only (which is more natural). Please review your code, edit it, and if problems remain, explain exactly what you want to accomplish and how the code fails to do that.

Comment: @Regent, your demo works great. But when I apply it with my page. It's not work and I'm working on it to see why.

Comment: @Wilf well, can you provide example of non-working page?

Comment: @Regent, This script seems to work on my page I don't know why. But yeah, thank you for your help => http://jsfiddle.net/My2xt/1/

Comment: @Wilf your provided code is pretty different from mine, but it also works, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `.css('font-size')` returns size in pixels, not in points. So, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357863/get-jquery-to-return-font-size-in-points) and avoiding code duplication it can be so:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL45pw5j/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#incfont').click(function()
    {
        changeFontValue(2);
    });

    $('#decfont').click(function()
    {
        changeFontValue(-2);
    });

    function changeFontValue(difference)
    {
        var newSize = Math.round(parseInt($('#reading_pane').css('font-size')) * 72 / 96) + difference;
        if (newSize >= 12 && newSize <= 20)
        {
            $('#reading_pane').css('font-size', newSize + 'pt');
        }
    }
});
```

**Note**: I also modified HTML:

```
<a id="incfont">A+</a>
<a id="decfont">A-</a>
```